# Plane Geometry, orthogonal line

Tags: geometry

I have an $(x,y)$ plane, a point $P(x_0,y_0)$, and a line "$l$" such as $x+y=a$. The distance from $P$ to a line being an orthogonal line we can draw it orthogonal. Here is what my teacher says :

The point $Q=(x_0,y_0)+d(\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2})$ is on the orthogonal line going from $P$ to $l$, $d$ being the distance between $P$ and $l.$

I don't understand why $Q$ is on the orthogonal line !
Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

A line with an equation $x+y=a$ can be re-written as $y=-x+a$.

All of these lines have gradient $-1$. These lines all go in the South-East direction. The lines perpendicular to these "South-East" lines must go in the North-East direction.

Notice that the vector $(1,1)$ goes in the North-East direction. In fact, any vector $(k,k)$, where $k > 0$ goes in the NE direction. In the example given by your teacher, $k = d/\sqrt{2}$.

You start at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ and then start moving to the NE. (Negative $d$ give SW movement.) This line is perpendicular to the line that runs NW-to-SE.

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer. But please can you explain me why he choose particularly $1/\sqrt(2)$ and not 3 or 10 or 15000 ?

Comment: @TheAnswer The main reason was because you used $d(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ in your own post. The reason your teacher used it is because the vector $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ is a "unit vector", it has length one. Draw yourself a right-angled triangle by going to the right and then going straight up. Label the base with length $1/\sqrt{2}$ and height $1/\sqrt{2}$. What is the length of the hypotenuse? Use Pythagoras: $h^2 = (1/\sqrt{2})^2 + (1/\sqrt{2})^2$. So $h^2 = 1/2 + 1/2$, meaning $h^2 = 1$ and so $h=1$.

Comment: @TheAnswer (Cont...) Because $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ is a unit vector, the number $d$ gives the true distance away from the line. The vector $d(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ is $d$ lots of $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ away from the line. Since $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ is length one, $d(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ is $d$ times the length, i.e. length $d$ away from the line.